# How to print on MobiWire MobiPrint 3 (Android)

Tags: android, printing, thermal-printer

I have MobiWire MobiPrint 3 device (Android **4.2.2**) with integrated thermal printer and I'm trying to make a simple app in Android Studio to print something on that printer.

Does anyone have API documentation for this device? Tried contacting Mobiwire and that didnt help..

What would be the best way for printing on Android 4.2.2, ESC/POS? I have to print text only (invoice).

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it most likely belongs to [android.SE]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Call this function in Activity or Fragment

```
fun print() {
    if (printer.printerStatus == Printer.PRINTER_STATUS_OK) {
        val printer = Printer.getInstance()
        printer.printText("Some Text")
        printer.printText("Another Text")
        printer.printText("Add as many Texts")
        // And finally add this line
        printer.printEndLine()
    } else {
        println("_print::(printerStatus:${status(printer.printerStatus)})")
    }
}

private fun status(s: Int) = when (s) {
    Printer.PRINTER_STATUS_OK -> "Printer Ok"
    Printer.PRINTER_ERROR -> "Error printing, try again"
    Printer.PRINTER_NO_PAPER -> "Not paper, insert paper and try again"
    Printer.PRINTER_STATUS_GET_FAILED -> "Printer not working correctly"
    Printer.PRINTER_STATUS_OVER_HEAT -> "Printer overheated, wait for it to cool"
    else -> "No printer found on this device"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi you should start by downloading mobiwire sdk , which comes with test example on how to print , then You can download a quick start demo android app , published by botpesa.com the demo can print and send data to api

Comment: Edit your answer and share a useful link